# user is not defined edit in angular

Tags: angular

i want to edit in angular8 i create a variable boolean isEdit to separate adds and edit.

hello, i want to edit in angular8 i create a variable boolean isEdit to separate adds and edit.

hello, i want to edit in angular8 i create a variable boolean isEdit to separate adds and edit.

**my-form-component.ts**

```
export class MyFormComponent implements OnInit {
  user={
    id:"",
    name:"",
    username:"",
    email:""
  }
  users:any[];
  isEdit:boolean=false;

  constructor(public dataService:DataServiceService) { 
    this.dataService.getPersone().subscribe(users=>{
      this.users=users;
});
  }

  editItem(user){
    this.isEdit=true;
    this.user=user;
  }
  mySubmit(isEdit){
    if (isEdit) {
      this.dataService.editPersone(this.user).subscribe(res=>{
        for(let i=0;i<this.users.length;i++){
          if(this.users[i].id==this.user.id){
            this.users.splice(i,1);
          }
        }
      this.users.push(user); //ligne error(user is not defined)
      });
    } else {
      this.dataService.addPersone(this.user).subscribe(user=>{
        this.users.unshift(user);
      }); 
    }   
  }
```

**my-form.componet.html**

```
 <form (submit)="mySubmit(isEdit)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nom">name</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='user.name' name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="prenom">usename</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='user.username' name="username" class="form-control" id="username">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">email</label>
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='user.email' name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <!--////////////////////////////////-->
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">

<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of users">
        <div class="pull-right" (click)="deleteItem(item.id)">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" >Delete</button>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right" (click)="editItem(item)">
          <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" >Edit</button>
      </div>
        <p> {{ item.id }} </p>
        <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
        <p>{{item.usename}} </p>
        <p>{{item.email}} </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**data-service.service**

```
 export class DataServiceService {
      constructor(public http:HttpClient) {
      }
      editPersone(user){
        return this.http.put('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + user.id,user);
      }
```

Comment: Try moving the code in the constructor to `ngOnInit()`

Comment: Please clearly state what your problem is? and show the error as well. As is stands it is impossible to help you.

Comment: No `user` is defined in the Observable response. Do you mean `res` or `this.user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` is undefined within the `mySubmit()` method. I am not sure what `user` refers to.

But I believe are you are referring to the `user`  property defined on the `MyFormComponent` class.

In addition, I would recommend you to handle the `Array.push()` operation within the `subscribe()` callback, instead of outside of the block, due to the asynchronous nature of HTTP requests. This way, it will ensure that the `user` object is pushed into the `users` array after the the observable from `editPersone` has been returned.

This is what you should be doing instead.

```
mySubmit(isEdit){
    if (isEdit) {
      this.dataService.editPersone(this.user).subscribe(res=>{
        for(let i=0;i<this.users.length;i++){
          if(this.users[i].id==this.user.id){
            this.users.splice(i,1);
          }
        }
        this.users.push(this.user); 
      });
    } else {
      this.dataService.addPersone(this.user).subscribe(user=>{
        this.users.unshift(user);
      }); 
    }   
  }
```